# Accidently forgot to merge master and pushed changes from another branch

Tags: git

It's really difficult to describe the workflow in one line. Anyway this is the scenario:

STEP 1: I have a story to work on, I've pulled the changes from master, created new branch and switched to:

```
git pull
git pull origin master
git checkout -b my_story
```

STEP 2: Some work was done

```
git commit -am "some changes"
git push origin my_story
```

STEP 3: After a while it occured that this branch needs some update.

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

At this point several changes were made to master (other branches from other devs were merged to master).

```
git checkout my_story
```

STEP 5: At this step I should merge local changes to master, but I forgot to do that.

```
should be: git merge master
```

I've provided some changes, committed and pushed:

```
git commit -am "some new changes"
git push origin my_story
```

STEP 6 (Result): In my PR I can see several other files changed. List of commits is extended by other developers (these are the changes that supposed to be merged in my local repository and I forgot to do that) which should not be there.

Question 1: How can I roll it back?

Question 2: How to configure local git repository, so it'll display on git status changes that were added by other developers? It wouldn't happen if I get list of modified files by other devs on git status and I know it's possible as I've seen it before on other repositories.

Comment: I don't understand why you're seeing other developers commits on your branch, it doesn't sound like you pulled from master into your own branch, or from someone elses branch either.

Comment: How would you see other devs changes on your LOCAL branch? Other devs are not working on your local machine. Unless you mean after they have merged their changes, in which case you would pull the latest changes in maser and then merge master into your current working branch, right?

Comment: you can roll back by `git checkout <your last correct commit hash>`, to find the hash `git log`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Changes/commits from other developers appeared in pull my request (so it's not my local branch, it's already remote branch) after git push origin my_story.

Comment: @JMullen Yes, but the thing is I HAVEN'T merge master into my current working branch

Comment: When you pull updates to master from the remote, it might be convenient to merge those changes into your branch, but it is not required. I'm not sure I understand what error you think you're seeing, but the steps you describe should not cause an error or incorrect behavior.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Yeah, you're right, it shouldn't. It turned out that it was a github issue - I can't really explain why github displays PR with commits from other devs. After setting up repo in seperate directory I've pulled all the changes from remote branch and it does not contain any commits other then mine.

Comment: So the end of the story is that within repository layer everything is completly fine however for some reason github UI presents those extra commits.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, the actions you described weren't responsible for the mess you are facing right now. To fix this, you can use cherry picks as follows:

First, check out the messed up feature branch and make a copy of it:

```
git checkout my_story
git branch my_story_backup
```

Now, within the my_story branch, you go back step by step until you are at a point where no more bad commits are in:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^1
```

Now you apply the good commits that you have still stored in your backup branch one by one:

```
git cherry-pick COMMIT_HASH
```

because you changed the history now, you need to force-push your feature branch. If that is not allowed in your project, you need to use a new branch:

```
git push --force my_story
```

When you are done and your my_story branch looks as desired, delete the my_feature_backup branch:

```
git branch -D my_story_backup
```